# What happens when we enable defender for key vault?

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-defender

We expect to enable Azure Defender for Key vault for approximately 200 key Vaults. I would like to know, Will there be any repercussions if I turn on Defender for Key Vault? Will this stop applications from reaching the vault? Has anyone ever experienced an incident or service disruption as a result of allowing the Defender for the key vault?

In the past, we have experienced an incident after activating the same for the SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling Microsoft Defender for Key Vault does not require any agent or extension and is an Azure-native threat protection service, which detects unusual and potentially harmful access to Key Vault accounts. It provides an additional layer of security intelligence for the keys, secrets and certificates stored in the Microsoft Key Vault by alerting you to suspicious or malicious access. This layer of security allows you to address threats without being a security expert, and without the need to manage third-party security monitoring systems. We’re not aware of any repercussions or similar you can find more information here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/defender-for-key-vault-introduction